# Psexec failing to connect the remote VM

Tags: windows, pstools

I have got two machines (*machine1* & *machine2*). My task is to execute few commands remotely via *PSEXEC* from *machine1* to *machine2*. Sadly these machines are from different network domains. Admin Share is enabled in both the machines.

*machine2* can be accessible only by establishing to VPN on *machine1*. *PSEXEC* works fine when I establish VPN on the machine1 to access *machine2*. I am also able to access Admin share via run ---> `\\ip\Admin$`

Tricky part here is to execute the *PSEXEC* without establishing VPN on *machine1*.
To achieve this I have disabled the firewalls on *machine2*. Now without VPN, I can connect *machine2* from *machine1* via RDP (Remote Desktop), but not able to successfully run *PSEXEC* nor able to access Admin share on *machine2*.

Below is the command/error:

Command: `PSexec \\{machineip} -u {username} -p {password} cmd`

Error:

```
Could not access {machineip}
The network path was not found
```

Guess as Admin share on *machine2* is not accessible without Establishing VPM *PSEXEC* fails to execute. If the above guess is valid, I would like to know how to access Admin Share from a different domain/network.

Comment: Can anyone have a look..? if any additional info needed ..please comment

Comment: Added an answer, but don't do this.  Try telling us what you're trying to do here/why you can't have the VPN established, and maybe we can figure out a way to do whatever it is without making your machine so incredibly insecure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fairly uncommon (and unsafe) to open up file sharing to the internet, which is what it looks like you're trying (or expecting) to do.  PSExec operates over ports `445` and `139`, and I'd expect that one or both of those ports are being blocked by one or both of the edge devices on the two networks at play here.

[And PSExec does require that you be able to access the administrative share to work](http://forum.sysinternals.com/faq-common-pstools-issues_topic15920.html).

So basically, the way you'd connect to a remote machine via PSExec is to open up ports `445` and `139` on the [hardware] firewall(s), establish a NAT rule (if needed), and then use the command normally.

However, do ***NOT*** actually do this, as opening up port 139 to the world is about the worst thing you can do.